# Editing MS Access Database using PHP on Linux

Tags: php, linux, ms-access, pdo, odbc

we have a Tool for managing the booked time at the different prjects of our customers an other things based on MS Access and we want to continue with it. Just for a better comfort I've made an PHP based Tool that is able to work with that database but it runs local on a windows system. Now I'd like to run it on our office webserver but that is a Linux system.
I use the PDO extension odbc and found the following docu to use the odbc extension on linux:

- https://gist.github.com/amirkdv/9672857

But this only allows me to read the databse.
Do anybody knows a way to get full access to a MS Access Databse on a Linux system?

I'm looking forward to your answers^^

Comment: A good question will include a) approach b) problem c) expected result

Comment: a) I have a PHP script using PDO via odbc extension with the Microsoft Access Driver to read/write the data of a *.mdb file.

b) I developed that script lacaly on windows and need to run it in the intranet on the linux based webserver with ful access (read/write) to the mdb file

c) if it possible to use an pdo extension I'll be happy because then I dont must rewrite my script

Answer (score 0):

The Access *database* (not the application) doesn't "run" anywhere, it's a file, so all you need an SMB share which, on Linux, is what *Samba* provides.

If you wish to run the Access *application* on Linux, you will need [Wine](https://www.winehq.org/).

Comment: thx for answering. Yes I mean that my PHP script running on linux appache webserver needs to interact (read/write) with a  *.mdb file. Sry but I'm never worked with Linux before, so how I can call that SMB with PHP?

Comment: Oh, I'm not into Linux, but plenty of stuff out there for the browsing.